# Difference between s3 bucket vs host files for Amazon Cloud Front

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

### Background

We have developed an e-commerce application where I want to use CDN to improve the speed of the app and also to reduce the load on the host.
The application is hosted on an EC2 server and now we are going to use Cloud Front.

### Questions

After reading a lot of articles and documents, I have created a distribution for my sample site. After doing all the experience I have come to know the following things. I want to be sure if am right about these points or not.

1. When we create a distribution it takes all the accessible data from the given origin path. We don't need to copy/ sync our files to cloud front.
2. We just have to change the path of our application according to this distribution CNAME (if cname is given).
3. There is no difference between placing the images/js/CSS files on S3 or on our own host. Cloud Front will just take them by itself.

The application will have thousands of pictures of the products, should we place them on S3 or its ok if they are on the host itself? Please share any good article to understand the difference of both the techniques.

Because if S3 is significantly better then I'll have to make a program to sync all such data on S3.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons to store the images on Amazon S3 rather than your own host (and then serve them via Amazon CloudFront):

**Less load on your servers**

Even though content is cached in Amazon CloudFront, your servers will still be hit with requests for the first access of each object from every edge location (each edge location maintains its own cache), repeated every time that the object expires. (Refreshes will generate a HEAD request, and will only re-download content that has changed or been flushed from the cache.)

**More durable storage**

Amazon S3 keeps copies of your data across multiple Availability Zones within the same Region. You could also replicate data between your servers to improve durability but then you would need to manage the replication and pay for storage on every server.

**Lower storage cost**

Storing data on Amazon S3 is lower cost than storing it on Amazon EBS volumes. If you are planning on keeping your data in both locations, then obviously using S3 is more expensive but you should also consider storing it *only* on S3, which makes it lower cost, more durable and less for you to backup on your server.

Reasons to NOT use S3:

- More moving parts -- maintaining code to move files to S3
- Not as convenient as using a local file system
- Having to merge log files from S3 and your own servers to gather usage information